# Problem when numerically solving Friedmann-Lemâitre equation

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve the F-L equation for a=1 to a = 0. However, when I try to solve it using odeint, at small values of a and t, I get negative values in the square root of my derivative, messing things up. Am I using the wrong method to solve it or am I missing something in my equations?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#FL equation
#(da/dt/a)^2 = H0^2*[(8.4*10^-5)/a^4 + 0.31/a^3  +  0.69 + (sum(omegas)-1)/a^2 )
H0=7.2e-11
omegaR = 8.4*10**-5
omegaM = 0.31
omegaA = 0.69

def model(a,t):
    RHS = H0**2*(omegaR/a**2 + omegaM/a + omegaA*a**2 +(omegaM+omegaA+omegaR-1) )
    dadt = np.sqrt(RHS)
    return dadt

# initial condition
y0 = 1

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,-10**14,2*10**7)

# solve ODE
a = odeint(model,y0,t)
```

[At low values of t, it just cuts off, which should not happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqs18.png)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run: you're missing all of your imports, and failed to define `odeint`.

Comment: I just forgot to paste them, I edited the question as to include everything and removed non essential code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're getting killed by computational errors.  First and foremost, you *still* haven't taken my suggestion to trace your problem.  A simple `print` in `model`, just before the failure point, shows what is going wrong at that point:

```
print(RHS, a**2, omegaR, omegaM, omegaA, omegaM+omegaA+omegaR-1)
```

This gets a stream of output that shows `a` slowly reducing until we finally get:

```
[3.21061361e-21] [7.33441396e-08] 8.400000000000001e-05 0.31 0.69 8.399999999997299e-05
[2.08853856e-22] [7.34183571e-08] 8.400000000000001e-05 0.31 0.69 8.399999999997299e-05
[-2.25330684e-21] [7.34793736e-08] 8.400000000000001e-05 0.31 0.69 8.399999999997299e-05
```

Your RHS figure gets so close to 0 that the huge discrepancies in the magnitude of values, and the tiny errors in binary representation, give you a negative result.

Alter your order of operations to preserve the least significant digits first.